# Unable to get values in action class of Multiple <s:select>

Tags: java, struts2, struts

I am using multiple `<s:select>`with multiple="true" And Code is

```jsp
<tr>
    <td>
       <s:select name="drAccountCode0" label=" Dr. A/c Code" labelposition="top" labelSeparator=" " list="account_name_list.{accountCode}" size="20" multiple="true" onclick="onTypeChange()" theme="simple"></s:select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
       <s:select name="drAccountCode1" label=" Dr. A/c Code" labelposition="top" labelSeparator=" " list="account_name_list.{accountCode}" size="20" multiple="true" onclick="onTypeChange()" theme="simple"></s:select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

how get values in Action Class

Comment: And code is .....? Fill in the blanks is the question?

Comment: What it is doing onTypeChange()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write in your action class:

```
 private List<Integer> yourMultiSelectName;
```

(In your case, `drAccountCode0` and `drAccountCode1`.)

Provide public getters and setters for each.

Comment: Please only use code tags for code, not your entire answer--have you noticed that we keep editing it out?